# How to install git-lfs on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: git

I am trying to install git-lfs package and it looks like expected paths are not Ubuntu friendly. From [Downloads section of git-lfs](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/releases/tag/v1.2.1) I choose Linux AMD64 file name `git-lfs-freebsd-amd64-1.2.1.tar.gz`, because .deb files are not available for Ubuntu, just Debian 7,8.

I am getting error: `install.sh: 19: install.sh: PATH+=:/usr/local/bin: not found` when executing install.sh.

Does anyone have a working solution on how to install git-lfs?

Comment: This link could be helpful if you didn't try it yet: https://help.github.com/articles/installing-git-large-file-storage/

Comment: I am actually using that same manual to install, I am stuck on the step number 3.

Comment: could you specify where the problem is  ?
like what's wrong in that step

Comment: Thank you, I found my problem, I was getting install error mentioned in my question because of using wrong interpreter.  One would expect .sh to work with `sh`.

Comment: The link above to help.github.com is MS Windows-specific. It does not work for Linux or other Operating Systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my solution, the problem was executing install.sh using `sh`:

The correct way is `sudo ./install.sh` or `sudo bash install.sh` instead of `sh install.sh`.

Answer (score 81):

There are in fact `.deb` files at https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs?filter=debs that you can install; the link you visited also hinted at this by stating that "All packages are available on PackageCloud now."

In any case, if you visit https://git-lfs.github.com/, the simplest way to install `git-lfs` is to follow the instructions at https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

Then, according to https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/INSTALLING.md#installing-packages, do

```
sudo apt-get install git-lfs
```

If you don't trust the source of `script.deb.sh` and are uncomfortable with running the script with `sudo bash`, you should definitely take a look at the script first.

Comment: this looked promising, but after running with sudo bash, I still cannot ```git lfs track``` - it says 'lfs' is not a git command

Comment: silly me, I still had to run ```sudo apt-get install git-lfs```

Comment: @tofutim You probably meant `sudo apt-get install git`?

Comment: nope, already installed git, but i needed git-lfs

Comment: @tofutim Ah okay, I see what you mean. It seems like an oversight to not include that in the installation instructions at https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install although it is mentioned in https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/INSTALLING.md#installing-packages.

Comment: Hi, I am using UBUNTU 16 and **git LFS v2.0.2**... How to change to **v2.4**? Even upgrading by `apt` with PPA, etc.  same v2.0.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I think you can ask a new question about it.

Comment: Thanks @edwinksl, posted at https://askubuntu.com/q/1032565/439867

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04.02, all I had to do was run `sudo apt install git-lfs`

Comment: Same for Ubuntu 20.04.5

Answer (score 16):

I was looking for a way to install entirely from the command line (server/VM setup), and was able to do so by following the instructions from the [documentation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation#ubuntu), copied below for reference.

1. `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`
2. `sudo curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`*
3. `sudo apt-get install git-lfs`
4. `git lfs install`

*The sudo in step 2 is my addition, and without it this step was failing silently. Maybe to do with my user permissions on the server? ymmv

Comment: The documentation link has the latest curls - https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation#ubuntu

Answer (score 16):

If anybody finds this thread from Google and is on a modern Ubuntu build (at least **21.04+**), simply do `sudo apt install git-lfs`