# How to upgrade git-LFS on Ubuntu 16 LTS?

Tags: git

It is similar to [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/799341/439867), but the problem here is to use `git LFS` *version 2.4*. Today, `apt`, etc. only installs *git LFS v2.0.2*, even upgrading by apt with PPA, etc. same v2.0.

How to change to v2.4?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official git LFS documentation at https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation, to install the latest version of git-lfs on any Ubuntu:

1. `curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`
2. `sudo apt-get install git-lfs`
3. `git lfs install`

Comment: The core of this solution is the same `curl`  and `apt-get` lines as @talamaki and same as [cited reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/799451/439867)... So, no news in this answer?

Comment: @PeterKrauss the significant difference is the link to the official github documentation. I don't like to run scripts from unknown sources and especially if they change my apt sources

Answer (score 1):

I just installed git-lfs version 2.4.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the `script.deb.sh` script from [packagecloud.io](https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install) git-lfs page.

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install git-lfs
```

Probably updating and upgrading your apt packages is enough for you.

Comment: The core of this solution is the same `curl`  and `apt-get` lines as the [cited reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/799451/439867)... So, no news in this answer?