# 18.04.3 LTS: Install git-lfs fails with not found error

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, git

I tried to install git-lfs using

`sudo apt install git-lfs` but experienced the following error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   git-lfs is already the newest version (2.9.2). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   Setting up git-lfs (2.9.2) ...
>   /usr/local/bin/git-lfs:
>   1: /usr/local/bin/git-lfs: 
>   ????: not found /usr/local/bin/git-lfs: 
>   5: /usr/local/bin/git-lfs: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
>   dpkg: error processing package
>   git-lfs (--configure):  installed git-lfs package post-installation
>   script subprocess returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing:  git-lfs
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The related solution in [install git-lfs on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799341/how-to-install-git-lfs-on-ubuntu-16-04) did not work for me either and flagged the same error. Does anyone have a workaround/solution?

Comment: Please do some proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `git-lfs` installed in `/usr/local/bin/git-lfs`.

This path is not maintained by APT. I would suggest to remove this file with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/git-lfs
```

and retry with package reinstallation:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git-lfs
```

and it will install `git-lfs` executable into correct location  - `/usr/bin/git-lfs` (see [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/git-lfs/filelist)).

Comment: Thank you. After removing the file, I was able to do `sudo apt install git-lfs`.